# Is there a way to directly insert data from a parquet file into PostgreSQL database?

Tags: bash, postgresql, hdfs, parquet

I'm trying to restore some historic backup files that saved in parquet format, and I want to read from them once and write the data into a PostgreSQL database.

I know that backup files saved using spark, but there is a strict restriction for me that I cant install spark in the DB machine or read the parquet file using spark in a remote device and write it to the database using `spark_df.write.jdbc`. Everything needs to happen on the DB machine and in the absence of spark and Hadoop only using Postgres and Bash scripting.

my files structure is something like:

```
foo/
    foo/part-00000-2a4e207f-4c09-48a6-96c7-de0071f966ab.c000.snappy.parquet
    foo/part-00001-2a4e207f-4c09-48a6-96c7-de0071f966ab.c000.snappy.parquet
    foo/part-00002-2a4e207f-4c09-48a6-96c7-de0071f966ab.c000.snappy.parquet
    ..
    ..
```

I expect to read data and schema from each parquet folder like `foo`, create a table using that schema and write the data into the shaped table, only using bash and Postgres CLI.

Comment: You can try the Parquet Foreign Data Wrapper https://github.com/adjust/parquet_fdw. You'll have to download the files from HDFS first.

Comment: @RemusRusanu It's quite interesting, thank you! I'm going to test it but the commits show that it is heavily under development yet. I'm looking for a solution based on processing the files using bash.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can using spark and converting parquet files to csv format, then moving the files to DB machine and import them by any tools.

```
spark.read.parquet("...").write.csv("...")
```

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.read_csv('mypath.csv')
df.columns = [c.lower() for c in df.columns] #postgres doesn't like capitals or spaces

from sqlalchemy import create_engine
engine = create_engine('postgresql://username:password@localhost:5432/dbname')

df.to_sql("my_table_name", engine)
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer! eventually, I decided to convert parquet files to CSV using spark in another machine, ship CSV files to DB machine and propagate tables using SQL `COPY foo FROM '/path/to/csv/foo' WITH (FORMAT CSV)` statement.

Comment: This is one of the best answers I've seen to the question "easiest way to ingest csv files into Postgres using python"

Comment: Alternatively, you can even skip the whole reading into Spark/writing to CSV step by just using `pyarrow.parquet` and reading directly into pandas with the `ParquetDataset` function - that could save an entire write and read of the data.

Comment: Why not use `pd.read_parquet` here instead of `spark.read.parquet` ?

Comment: Saving to CSV is a bad idea. CSV is an outdated format that is error-prone (it's quite common to have commas in strings). PyArrow is much better.

Answer (score 6):

I made a library to convert from parquet to Postgres’ binary format: https://github.com/adriangb/pgpq.

It lets you use PyArrow to read the parquet data and your postgres driver of choice to write it out (e.g. psycopg).

Update: it's been pointed out to me that DuckDB can do this as well. Here's a benchmark where I show how to do it with both pgpq and DuckDB: [permalink](https://github.com/adriangb/pgpq/blob/4fe8600f23ead94de129bb57fbd1ba12b3f5b389/py/benches/copy.ipynb). Both perform about the same but DuckDB is of course much more widely used, better tested and more versatile.

Answer (score 1):

This page was viewed more than 34000 times, and many of the views do not require a bash-specific solution.

### General answer about working with Parquet in PostgreSQL

The best is to use only SQL. The most recommended resources are:

- **FDW**, https://github.com/adjust/parquet_fdw
- **JDBC**  driver adapted as a FOREIGN TABLE, https://github.com/pgspider/jdbc_fdw

For example to read *Parquet file on Amazon S3*, use JDBC. To local files, use FDW.

---

If you encounter issues with local files, you can try to work around them by running the [**pgpq**](https://github.com/adriangb/pgpq) command directly in bash.